# SQL Server select ids where number of rows is above specified amount

Tags: sql-server

I am not very familiar with SQL Server but I know the basics. I want to do something like the below but this does not work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr2, shopid AS Expr1
FROM Orders
WHERE (Expr2 > '5000')
```

I basically need to pull out `shopIds` where they have over 5000 orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MSSQL won't allow aliases in a WHERE or HAVING clause, so you'll need to repeat the aggregate field. You'll also want to Group by the Shop Id if you want to count the orders per shop:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Expr2, 
shopid AS Expr1 
FROM         
Orders 
GROUP BY ShopId
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 5000)
```

Comment: +1: In my SQL I had `COUNT(Expr2)` which was wrong.  Well spotted.

Comment: *Unfortunately* only MySQL *doesn't* follow the SQL standard and allows aliases in the wrong place. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by for how to make MySQL behave correctly

Comment: Unfortunately for the OP :) Use of a CTE would allow for a DRY implementation.